# How to get SINGLE value from ViewBag or ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this:

```
_gameService = new GameService();
            ViewBag.Data = _gameService.JoinGame(userID, gameID, whoJoin);
            return View("Game");
```

This code gets list of users that are ingame, and pass it to game view. Nothing fancy.

On the game view I need to get single values from ViewBag in diffrent places, like UserID, GameID, Moves etc.

Using Strongly Typed view is not an option, because I need list of users that are in game, and strongly-typed view give me only option to store single user(which won't work in multiplayer game)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use strongly typed views. [Here is small intro](http://www.howmvcworks.net/OnViews/BuildingAStronglyTypedView). They are really more flexible. You can create class like `PlayerList` with a field of `List` type and then iterate it in your view ([Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985333/passing-parameterized-list-to-view-in-mvc-using-entity-framework)). And here is [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314933/asp-net-mvc-how-do-i-pass-a-list-from-a-class-in-model-to-a-repeater-in-a-view) how to pass strongly typed lists to View.